# spyder won't show the matplotlib window

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

i am using spyder to run the following script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([2,1,3])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

input('something')
```

the problem is, that the matplotlib-window appears at the end of the script (after i entered 'something')

when i'm executing this script in a terminal the window appears and i can enter 'something' simultaneously - this is what i need.

does someone has an idea what causes this problem?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the problem using `spyder`. The graph is showing up before the `input` command.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to launch the input in another thread, which in python is a huge pain. The problem is caused because the matplotlib image painting s blocked by the next action. you can set ioff() and when the user see the picture and it closes it the program continues to the input, otherwise both actions are executed at the same time.

Comment: Would `plt.draw()` and `plt.pause(0.1)` solve the issue?

Comment: @ kazemakase: yes     plt.draw() and     plt.pause(0.1) solves the problem, but the matplotlib window is frozen then. (which doesnt happen, when i execute the script in a terminal)

@ leb: are there any special configurations which u made in spyder?

@ Santi Peñate-Vera: i want the script to continue without the user closing the window
when i run it in a terminal both actions are executed at the same time - thats what i want also in spyder

Comment: @danny_w123, there's no nothing you can do in Spyder to prevent `input` from blocking Matplotlib plots. You simply can't use it in Spyder in combination with plots.